# Como comparar campos de tres tablas distintas

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente situación: Estoy haciendo una comparación en tres las tablas,en dos ellas  hay campos **vacíos** **(college, contact_person)**, los cuales necesito excluir de la comparación y que solo me de las diferencia de los que no coincidan y no sean **vacíos**.

El problema que tengo, es que si coloco la condición de quitar los que sean **vacíos** en la columna de correo me quita los del teléfono que son distintos y si quito los **vació** de la columna de teléfono de cualquiera de las tablas **(college, contact_person)** me sucede que me quita los de correo que son distintos.

El resultado que necesito, es que me de los datos que sean distintos tanto en correo como en teléfono y que no sean vacíos. A continuación le dejo mi consulta a ver si me pueden ayudar.

Gracias.

**Consulta completa:**

```
SELECT college.CollegeID, 
       college.SEPEconomicKey, 
       college.Namecol,
       contact_person.Email,
       datosdriver.correo,
       college.Telephone1,
       datosdriver.telefono,
       nivel,
       NameLev 
FROM college 
INNER JOIN contact_person ON college.CollegeID = contact_person.CollegeID 
INNER JOIN datosdriver ON college.SEPEconomicKey = datosdriver.clave 
INNER JOIN level ON level.levelID = college.SEPLavel 
WHERE 1 AND datosdriver.correo <> (contact_person.Email OR contact_person.Emal2) 
AND datosdriver.telefono <> (college.Telephone1 OR college.Telephone2) 
AND (contact_person.Emal2 <> '' OR college.Telephone2 <> '' ) 
ORDER BY SEPEconomicKey ASC
```

**Condición que coloco para las diferencias:**

```
WHERE 1 
AND datosdriver.correo <> (contact_person.Email OR contact_person.Emal2) 
AND datosdriver.telefono <> (college.Telephone1 OR college.Telephone2)
```

**Condición para quitar los vacíos**

```
AND (contact_person.Emal2 <> '' OR college.Telephone2 <> '' )
```

Le coloco un ejemplo de lo que me devuelve y lo que necesito:

Este registro, muestra el segundo teléfono vació pero el primero esta correcto y el correo es distinto, me tiene que mantener el registro y eso no me esta sucediendo porque al estar el segundo teléfono  vació me quita el registro.

> Teléfono 1 de BD: 555XXXXXXX
>
> Teléfono 2 de BD:
>
> Teléfono Contacto:
>
> Teléfono de Drive: 555XXXXXX
>
> Correo 1 de BD: aaab@hotmail.com
>
> Correo de Drive: aaac@hotmail.com

Comment: Intentaste usar left join o right join en lugar de inner join? creo que por ahí va tu problema...

Comment: Mostras datos de ejemplo? y un resultado esperado con esos datos de ejemplo? y porque where 1??? porque????

Comment: Si provee pero lo que me sucede cuando uso left y right me muestra algunos que no tienen diferencias y no me valida si esta vació o no

Comment: Como comentó gbianchi, datos de ejemplo y resultado esperado para poder ayudarte

Comment: Coloque el ejemplo con datos de lo que me esta sucediendo